# How to get a Field of type “image” not to have a delete checkbox?

Tags: admin, adminhtml, image, magento-1, adminform

How to get a Field of type "image" not to have a delete checkbox ? As it's a required attribute for my form, I don't need the delete checkbox.

Here is my addField example :

```
$fieldset->addField('filename', 'image', array(
                                'label'     => Mage::helper('example')->__('Example image'),
                                'required'  => true,
                                'name'      => 'filename',
                    ));
```

Comment: actually `delete` is good functionality. why you want to remove it?

Comment: Because the field is needed. Why removing it if it's a needed attribute ? You can add multiple images if you want and remove the extra images, but only one is needed so you can't remove the last one. Seems logical, no ? I think it's a good functionnality to add, don't you ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to create a custom renderer for the image.
For this create a class in one of your modules called `[Namespace]_[Module]_Block_Adminhtml_Helper_Image_Required` with this content

```
<?php 
class [Namespace]_[Module]_Block_Adminhtml_Helper_Image_Required extends Varien_Data_Form_Element_Image{
    protected function _getDeleteCheckbox() 
    {
        return '';
    }
}
```

Then in your form block, right above your field (or higher) add this lines

```
$fieldset->addType('required_image', '[Namespace]_[Module]_Block_Adminhtml_Helper_Image_Required');
```

and define your field like this:

```
$fieldset->addField('filename', 'required_image', array(
                            'label'     => Mage::helper('example')->__('Example image'),
                            'required'  => true,
                            'name'      => 'filename',
                ));
```