# Magento 2 : remove delete image checkbox from admin edit form

Tags: adminform, image-upload, checkbox, magento-2.1.7

I have add an image upload field in my modules edit form using-

```
$fieldset->addField(
    'image',
    'image',
    [
        'name' => 'image',
        'label' => __('Image'),
        'id' => 'image',
        'title' => __('Image'),
        'class' => 'required-entry',
        'required' => true,
    ]
);
```

While editing row it displays checkbox to delete image, I have only one image upload field and that is required also.  So I want to remove this checkbox. How can I remove this checkbox?

Comment: a similar solution exists in magento-1.x https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/73870 so you can use the same for magento 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Manashvi Suggested I tried to solve it the way it was done in Magento 1.x  and it worked. I created  a custom renderer for the image. and created a class in my module 
    `[Namespace]_[Module]_Block_Adminhtml_Helper_Image_Required` with this content

```
class Required extends \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\Image
{
    protected function _getDeleteCheckbox()
    {
        return '';
    }
}
```

Then in my form block, right above  field added this lines

```
$fieldset->addType('required_image', 'Namespace\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Helper\Image\Required');
```

and defined field like this:

```
$fieldset->addField(
    'image',
    'required_image',               [
    'name' => 'image',
    'label' => __('Image'),
    'id' => 'image',
    'title' => __('Image'),
    'class' => 'required-entry',
    'required' => true,
    ]
);
```

Comment: I am trying to achieve the same. but i get error: Cannot declare class Required because the name is already in use. Even i change it's name to something else, still i get same error with that name. Any idea?

Comment: such issue occurs in case when you have declared same class more than once, please check your file path and class name

Comment: but even if i change class name to any other name for e.g. RequiredImage, Still i get the same error: Cannot declare class RequiredImage because the name is already in use. (i am using magento 2.2)

Comment: Ok i found the issue. Just forgot to add namespace line on top of the class file!